# How to make this motion graphics effect using geometry nodes?

Tags: animation, geometry, geometry-nodes

I have tried to recreate an effect similar to this one (in the 3:30 minute) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iqMVl2F1d4A using blender's geometry nodes.

The basic shape is an extruded circle mesh with the geometry nodes modifier.

[image]

[image]

The idea was to animate the circle using some texture and bind this to the frame value. Other circles are just a repetitions of the same geometry and texture but offseted by a few frames. It basically works, but the problem comes when i want to add more circles - the node tree is just getting huge. Can anyone help to make it more efficient?

Answer (score 4):

I got this effect by displacing an array of circle meshes by a 3D noise texture and animating the Z position on the texture.

This is my Geometry Nodes tree :

[image]

This is the Material Shader :

[image]

This is the result :

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It's a very nice result. I tried to do it with a Mesh Line node to get more circles but I never moved a noise texture i the Z position.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a stack of lines using instances on points and then use realize instances to convert them back into lines:

[image]

In this case, all points from different circles will be in one set. So to get line index you need to do a simple math: divide point ID by count of the vertexes in row:

[image]

I'm using Scene time, it's 3.1 node. In 3.0 use driver as you used to use.

Comment: Scaling instances by it's ID is very helpful with animations. The final result is what I asked for but sometimes the lines take some strange shapes from the top view. Adding Combine XYZ node after the Scale node (and set Z value to 0 to ignore the Z axis movement) solves the problem.